# Spam requests to Google app engine

Tags: google-app-engine

We switched over to use Google App Engine a couple of weeks ago and for some reason we see a lot of spam requests coming to the page that was not present before.

Most of them is coming from "google inc" according to analytics -> Audience -> Technology -> Network with browser version 47.0.2403.89 going to similar paths as below:

```
/some-path/'-function()%7Bxssdetected(10355911)%7D()-%22%3E%5C%22%3E%3CscrIpt%3Exssdetected(10355911)%3C%2FscrIpt%3E%3CaUdio+src%3Dx+oNerror%3Dxssdetected(10355911)%3E%3C%22-'-function()%7Bxssdetected(10355911)%7D()/
```

and they are to the appspot domain not the custom domains

What is this?  Why is google spamming our page with these strange requests?

Answer (score 0):

Ok.  Figured it out.  It was Google App Engine -> Security Scans